# detach vhd by disk number

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, vhd

I want to replace my `system` call of Powershell's `Dismount-VHD -DiskNumber`, with proper WinAPI. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the only way WinAPI provides for detaching a VHD is [DetachVirtualDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-detachvirtualdisk), which requires a handle returned by [OpenVirtualDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-openvirtualdisk), which requires a path string, which I cannot use for VHDs that exist on network paths, because my program is (necessarily) not running as a domain user.

Comment: If Powershell can do this operation it is probably calling a .NET API somewhere, so you should try to trace it to see what it's calling...

Comment: Powershell itself uses the Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.dll .NET dll. This dll uses WMI for that, not any public Win32 API. This is the WMI method it calls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/detachvirtualharddisk-msvm-mountedstorageimage but it's not super easy. You'd have to determine the Msvm_MountedStorageImage WMI instance that corresponds to a disk number. If you really want C/C++, interoping powershell or the Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.dll maybe easier.

Comment: Ach — I expected it might be MI, after reading some other things earlier. Yeah, using MI from C++ is way more work than just generating and `system`ing Powershell one-liners at runtime and parsing the output.  So I guess the only improvement I can make to this thing is, like you said, interop-ing via C++/CLI.

Comment: Arrgh— sometime in the last few months, a Windows Update made it so `Dismount-VHD -DiskNumber` fails unless your user has access to the filesystem where the VHD is stored. So, for example, a service running as the System user cannot detach a VHD mounted from a file on the network.  So, in my case, I now *have to* carry a handle around. (Assuming they haven’t broken DetachVirtualDisk in the same way!)

Comment: OK, I confirm at least DetachVirtualDisk still works, even if the VHD is on a network share and the caller does not have domain credentials. Assuming all other handles are closed and/or(?) the thing was originally attached using `ATTACH_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_PERMANENT_LIFETIME`.